# What does "(卐)" as part of 两分字元 mean?

Tags: meaning, characters

The site [zisea](http://zisea.com) likes to give a *two-part component* breakdown of every character.

One of their classifications comes with a `(卐)` next to it.

For instance:

[敢](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=6562) is split up like:

> 两分字元：耳(卐) 攵

[殷](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=6BB7) is split up like:

> 两分字元：厂(卐) 殳

[橐](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=6A50) is split up like:

> 两分字元：十(卐) 木

The entry for the character [卐](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=5350) itself doesn't allude to this usage:

> 拼音wan4
>
> 古代印度宗教的吉祥标志。显现金光，如来佛胸前有卐字。中国唐代武则天定音为【万】。义为“吉祥万德之所集”。佛经中又写作【卍】。

What does "(卐)" as part of 两分字元 mean?

Comment: 卍 and 卐 are two different character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On http://zisea.com/zslf.htm# you can see this:

> 卐=难拆字元

So it is just a "symbol" used on the site to represent parts that are hard to identify.

It is not universal.

Comment: Also it looks like it may only stand for one stroke: `【卐】【1画】`.